# SharePoint ContentBySearchWebPart shows OneNote sections instead of OneNote documents

Tags: search-results, content-search-web-part, onenote

We are using SharePoint 2016. I have added a ContentBySearchWebpart on the welcome page. Here I show the recently added/modified documents. In the search results I see allot of OneNote results because search is showing OneNote sections and not OneNote document. How can hide the OneNote sections in the search results and allow OneNote documents?

**This is my search query:**

(Author:{User.Name} OR  ModifiedBy:{User.Name}) AND IsDocument:1

Answer (score 3):

You can exclude files with the `.one` extension, which represent OneNote sections, by adding `NOT FileType:"one"` to your search query.

Note that OneNote notebooks are really folders, not documents, so you'll need to remove the `IsDocument:1` property restriction to get them to appear in your search results.

You can add a property restriction of `contentclass:STS_ListItem` to get any type of list item, folder, or document (excluding sites, lists, and libraries) although that will also include things like tasks unless you explicitly exclude them.

Comment: thank you. I will try this solution and let you know if it works.

Comment: It looks like it works, but because I removed IsDocument:1 I see now also other results like pictures in picturelibraries and sites. I would like to show only the results like: OneNote, Word, Excel, PowerPoint, Access, PDF. How can I do this?

Comment: I believe instead of `IsDocument:1` you can add a property restriction of `contentclass:STS_ListItem` to get any type of list item, folder, or document (excluding sites, lists, and libraries) although that would also include things like tasks unless you explicitly exclude them.